# Custom HTML Element Extending the <script> Element?

Tags: javascript, element, extends

The customary `<script type="text/template">` [tag for client-side processing](http://braddunbar.net/2013/08/19/underscore-templates/) isn't sufficient for my purposes because [it isn't nestable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322541/nested-javascript-templates-is-this-possible-valid). So I'm trying to extend it to work around this limitation.

Basically I have some raw html with embedded images that I want to parse the content client-side using javascript. I like the script tag because images inside it are not loaded by the browser. But when the html contains script tags, they break my application. Here's how I'm trying to extend the tag:

```
    <script>
        var scriptData = document.registerElement('script-data', {
            prototype: HTMLScriptElement.prototype
        });
        captureStart();
    </script>
```

When executed, chrome throws the following error:

```
Uncaught NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'registerElement' on 'Document': Registration failed for type 'script-data'. The prototype is already in-use as an interface prototype object.
```

**Update:**

**Disputing my intentions or suggesting alternative methods is fine, however I still want an answer to my initial question: how does one extend the script tag?**

How I'm using this is actually more complicated. I'm basically using this to "capture" the whole body of my HTML document, so that I can manipulate things before they are displayed. It's unconventional, I know. But I'm exploring it as a type of academic study.

The benefits to this approach include:

- The html validates
- The code is light-weight, and I hope better supported than solutions like mobify.js
- I am able to modify content before the browser loads image resources

The challenges to this approach include:

- The body of the document can have 3rd party modules/widgets with script tags or html comments.
- I can't escape inline script tags. They need to remain in-tact because browsers with javascript disabled will display the document normally.

My proposed solution to these problems:

- Extending the prototype of the script tag would allow me to use a custom tag that I know will never appear in other components.

Here's a larger sample of the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Script Test</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <script>document.write("<script type='text/html' id='text-html'>");</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" alt="" width="600" height="400"/>
    </body>
</html>
<!--</script>
<script>
    var content = document.getElementById("text-html");
    document.write(content.innerHTML);
    content.parentNode.removeChild(content);
</script>-->
```

Comment: Depending on the templateng you're using, you shouldn't need to literally nest templates. Just define your different templates and use them together

Comment: @Ian I don't think I'm nesting templates? There's just one template, with raw html inside. I have limited control over the content, so script tags could appear in some cases.

Comment: There’s the `<template>` element, but you’d probably be better off just escaping `</script>`.

Comment: @minitech I can't manipulate the raw content. Images inside the template element are still loaded.

Comment: Not being able to manipulate the raw content is a plain old security flaw, so please find some way to do that. Also, no, they’re not, but your browser probably doesn’t support it.

Comment: @minitech If I polyfill the template tag, will browsers that don't support it cease to load the images?

Comment: Probably. `display: none` ought to, even.

Comment: @minitech I've updated my question to explain my use case. I can't escape the html because in some cases, it would actually be displayed. I do have control over my content and website security. Display:none is not supported in older browsers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158540/does-displaynone-prevent-an-image-from-loading

Comment: Oh, sorry. To answer your original question: one doesn’t extend the `<script>` tag. It’s a very special case. Anyways, what do you mean by “in some cases, it would actually be displayed”?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58282/discussion-between-skibulk-and-minitech).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** Use `Object.create()` for the prototype object. The following code allows you to extend the `script` element, and represents the way `document.registerElement()` is meant to be used.

```js
var scriptData = document.registerElement('script-data', {
    prototype: Object.create(HTMLScriptElement.prototype);
});
```

#### Long answer

Consider this variation on your original code:

```js
var scriptDataProto = HTMLScriptElement.prototype;
// The next statement throws a DOMException of type "NotSupportedError".
var scriptData = document.registerElement('script-data', {
    prototype: scriptDataProto
});
```

The source of the exception is illustrated here:

```js
scriptDataProto === HTMLScriptElement.prototype; // true
```

You're providing a reference to `HTMLScriptElement.prototype`, meaning that you want to use the *exact same prototype* for the custom script element you're creating. It's not very well documented yet, but the prototype you provide can't be a reference to any of the built-in `HTML[*]Element` prototypes; you have to provide a new prototype object.

If you want to inherit from the `<script>` tag's prototype, then you have to **create a new prototype object** that inherits from `HTMLScriptElement.prototype` by using `Object.create()`.

```js
var scriptDataProto = Object.create(HTMLScriptElement.prototype);
scriptDataProto === HTMLScriptElement.prototype; // false
```

If you'd like, you can then add new members to this prototype without affecting the base `HTMLScriptElement.prototype`.

```js
scriptDataProto.foo = function() {
    alert('Hello world!');
};
var scriptData = document.registerElement('script-data', {
    prototype: scriptDataProto
});
var element = new scriptData();
element.foo(); // alerts "Hello world!"
document.body.appendChild(element);
element.onclick = element.foo;
```

For further reading, [HTML5 Rocks has a well-written article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) that really helped me understand how custom elements work.