# Why does adding </script> in a comment break the parser?

Tags: javascript, html

Why does adding `</script>` in a comment break the parser? Is this a bug or is there something in the documentation I've overlooked?

I've tested this in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Internet Explorer and they all produce the same result.

**Single-line comment:**

```js
function Foo(){
  // </script>
  alert("bar");
};

Foo();
```

**Multi-line comment:**

```js
function Foo(){
  /*
      </script>
  */
  alert("bar");
};

Foo();
```

Comment: The html parse doesn't know anything about the language and the syntax of the script that is written between the `<script>` tags, the language of the `script` can be anything (the default is javascript in html5). As of that the occurrence  of `</script>` is the only indication for the parser that the script ended.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write

Comment: @t.niese has it on the head; `<script>` can be used for **any scripting language**, not just Javascript. It has no concept of comments.

Comment: @t.niese That makes sense. I guess my first mistake was to believe that the html parser would hand over the job to an appropriate scripting parser, in this particular case a javascript parser.

Comment: Any serious use of scripts in HTML should be minified anyway, especially if not a separate resource. IOW, this shouldn't affect production code.

Comment: It *does* hand over the script to an appropriate parser, how do you think your JavaScript gets executed? But, how does the HTML parser know where the script begins and where it ends, i.e. which part to hand off to the scripting parser? Well, it begins with `<script>` and ends with `</script>`.

Comment: You'll get similar results if you do this: `<style> /*</style>*/ </style>`. Seems like this issue could have been avoided if everything recognized HTML comment syntax. On a related note, it's too bad the HTML parser doesn't also look for script start tags while it's looking for script end tags. Then things like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32569470/2759272) would be possible.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

This happens because HTML parser as defined by W3C is totally separated from the JavaScript parser. After the `<script>` tag it looks for the closing `</script>`, regardless that it's inside comments or strings, because it treats JS code as normal text.

Comment: To add, it would be very bad if it worked any other way. Browsers that don't support JavaScript still need to be able to find the closing `</script>` without knowing the parsing rules of the language. And while browsers that don't support JavaScript may be uncommon (although they do exist, even current ones), the same argument can be made for *any* language that has *ever* been supported in *any* browser. Would Firefox need to know the VBScript parsing rules if the page contains a script that's designed to only work on IE?

Answer (score 33):

The HTML parser does not parse JavaScript. It only parses HTML elements, denotated by `<tag>` and `</tag>` tags. It has no idea that something is a JavaScript comment. When it sees the `</script>` closing tag, it assumes the script element is being closed. The same would occur in whatever context the string `</script>` appeared; for instance, `console.log("</script>")` would yield the same behavior.

This is a pretty good reason not to embed scripts inside HTML, but rather to include them externally.

Comment: Note that if you actually want to log the string literal `</script>` in your JavaScript code, you can write `console.log("<\/script>")`.

Answer (score 11):

You can HTML-escape embedded JavaScript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

function Foo(){
 // </script>
  alert("bar");
};

Foo();

//-->
</script>
```

Thus, the whole JavaScript code is treated as HTML comment by HTML parser and HTML comment lines are ignored by JavaScript interpreter.

Comment: I disagree. This was good practice a decade or two ago, before HTML parsers started to treat the content of `<script>` tags as the equivalent of CDATA. Now, it's just extra junk in your code. The only case this is necessary is when your scripts contain the magic character sequence `</script>`, **or** you're dealing with XHTML, in which case you're better off wrapping the script in a real CDATA.

Comment: @torazaburo thanks, updated the answer

Comment: The historical reason for this was actually that some early browsers (Mosaic, Netscape 1, etc.) didn't recognize the `<script>` tag at all, and the parsing rules were such that unrecognized tags were ignored and their content rendered as if the tags weren't there. You needed the SGML comment to prevent text rendering in browsers that didn't, but that was a JavaScript syntax error, so the SGML had to be written as JavaScript comments. It hasn't actually been necessary since about 1997, when Lynx 2.7 was released (Lynx being the text mode browser of choice for the blind at the time).

Comment: This might provide an *alternative* but doesn't answer the actual question of *why* the `</script>` tag is obeyed by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

An easier workaround would be embedding comments:

```
function Foo(){
  //<!-- </script> -->
  alert("bar");
};

Foo();
```

It will comment the line for javascript AND for html.