# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' on valid javascript

Tags: javascript

I have what I believe is valid javascript. However I get this: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'. Removing any of the script blocks, or changing around the order in the 'a' string fixes the issue. Why is that?

```html
<script>
let a = "<!-- <script>";
</script>
<script></script><!-- --><script></script>
```

Comment: What you have is HTML, not javascript. The `<script>` is not legal javascript. It is a signal to HTML that what comes next is javascript.

Comment: @RaymondChen He put it in the HTML block of the snippet editor.

Comment: May i ask, why you are writing this specific piece of code? Since it looks as if it was purposely written to mess with parsers.

Comment: According to [the HTML spec: 4.12.1.3 Restrictions for contents of script elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements), the character sequence `<script` is disallowed in embedded script. What you have above is a minor variation of the very first Example in that section.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it without the last two script blocks, I just needed the comment after the first script.

Comment: I was testing XSS vulnerabilties in my app and got this error. There was a lot of code that I removed to get this simplified version

Comment: use ` let a = "<!-- \u003cscript>";` and everything should be fine

Comment: @RaymondChen I'll make that the accepted answer if you write an answer

Comment: That's okay. You can write and accept your own answer. I don't need imaginary points.

Comment: That will teach you to use inline `<script>`s. They don't cache, either.

Comment: @StackSlave What if the script that contains that inlined script is cached? Would that cache hold an evergreen script? Seems like a nice cache invalidation technique 

Comment: I'm saying do like `<script src='yourJavaScriptPage.js'></script>`. Now that String with the script tag in it won't be an issue.

Comment: This is legacy embedded PHP that renders to this :(

Answer (score 1):

You get the same error with:

```html
<script>
document.write('<script>alert("foo")</script>');
</script>
```

When "parsing" the page the browser sees this as an attempt to nest a `<script>` block inside another one. e.g.

```
<script>
  <script>alert("foo")</script>
</script>
```

The solution is to trick the browser to see something different:

```html
<script>
document.write('<scr' + 'ipt>alert("foo")</scr' + 'ipt>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like opening a `<script>` tag will make interpreter wait for javascript code until the last `</script>` is found, except if there is a second `<script>` opened with javascript inside of it.

Simple `<script></script>` will be interpreted as part of the JS code, which is invalid.

Might be related to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322541/nested-javascript-templates-is-this-possible-valid).

[image]
[image]